# How do I sort based on a vector of type template

Tags: sorting, c++11, templates, vector

How do I pass in / use a `vector <T> vect` in `sort()` function ?

Thanks for the help.

I have a few classes:

```
class A {
  int x;
  int getX() {return x;}
}

class B : public A {
  int x;
}
```

and a few vectors :

```
vector< A > a_vector;
vector< B > b_vector;
```

and I would like to call `sortByX` for these 2 classes

```
template <typename T>
void sortByX(const vector<T> &vectorName, int num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        // Sort In Ascending
    case 0:
        sort(vectorName.begin(), vectorName.end(), sortByX_ascending);
        break;
        // Sort In Descending
    case 1:
        sort(vectorName.begin(), vectorName.end(), sortByX_descending);
        break;
    }
}
```

Below are the comparator functions:

```cpp
bool sortByX_ascending(const A &lhs, const A &rhs) { return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX(); }

bool sortByX_descending(const A &lhs, const A &rhs) { return lhs.getX() > rhs.getX(); }
```

and when I invoke

```
sortByX(a_vector, 0);
```

I got an error

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:4016:17: error: no matching function for call to 'swap'
                swap(*__first, *__last);
                ^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:4201:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__sort<bool (*&)(const A &, const A
      &), const A *>' requested here
    __sort<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __comp);
```

Comment: `A::x` and `B::x` are two distinct and different variables. And `A::getX` have no idea that `B::x` even exists.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the error message is pretty straightforward. Inside `sort`, it's trying to swap two different elements of the vector (in order to end up with a sorted vector), but it doesn't know how.

what happens if you add this to your classes?

```
class A {
....
public:
   void swap (A &other) { std::swap(x, other.x); }
...
```

Also, what is `Class`? (note the uppercase 'C')

Comment: The OP needs a way to compare two objects, a la, `operator<`. Providing a `swap` member function will be of no use.

Comment: The error message says "error: no matching function for call to 'swap'"

Comment: I am not sure how the OP got that error but after a few tweaks to their code, it builds successfully without needing a  `swap` function. See https://ideone.com/fc7nim.